# Including lists from a .txt file. Editing it and saving it for the next time is starts

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, text-files

I have a text document in which I have 10 lists.. all in python syntax.. how can I include them to the program?

this is how they look:

```
#B Smjena
ponedjeljakB = ["Hrvatski", "Hrvatski", "Biologija", "Geografija", "Geografija", "Matematika", "Kemija", "Slobodan Sat"]
utorakB = ["Slobodan Sat", "Slobodan Sat", "Sat Razrednika", "Njemacki", "Njemacki", "Racunalstvo", "Racunalstvo"]
#etc....
```

How can I include them to the program everytime it starts? Edit them, read from them, save them for the next time app starts without using any advanced methods?

Comment: You could always read the whole file and run `exec` on the string, e.g., `with open(filename, 'r') as f: exec(f.read())`. Of course, you always run the risk of someone injecting some malicious code in your text file that you end up executing. You can save a string representation of a list by doing `f.write(repr(my_list))`. However, I think there might be more appropriate ways to load and store your data.

Comment: An alternative to `exec` is `import`.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.  Executing a code file and editing a text file (that happens to be code) are two different things (and two different quesitons).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement) to execute the dynamic python code

```
>>> txt = 'ponedjeljakB = ["Hrvatski", "Hrvatski", "Biologija", "Geografija", "Geografija", "Matematika", "Kemija", "Slobodan Sat"]'
>>> exec(txt)
>>> ponedjeljakB
['Hrvatski', 'Hrvatski', 'Biologija', 'Geografija', 'Geografija', 'Matematika', 'Kemija', 'Slobodan Sat']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a text file that has python code in it, you can simply read the file and exec the contents.

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    exec(f.read())

print ponedjeljakB, utorakB
```

This will work, but is generally considered very bad.

- If someone changes the text file, you could be running malicious code unknowingly.
- For someone else looking at your code, it won't be entirely clear what code or symbols was brought in with the `exec()`.

Alternatively, you can store python objects (like lists) using json.  Which is much safer and doesn't come with the danger of malicious code injection.

```
import json

my_lists = {
    'ponedjeljakB': [1,2,3,4],
    'utorakB': [5,6,7,8],
}

# Writing out lists.
with open('filename.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(my_lists , f)

# Reading them back in.
with open('filename.json', 'r') as f:
    my_lists = json.load(f)
```

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, pickle could also work, but is also suffers from the dangers of malicious code execution and isn't human-readable or editable.